# Firebase Analytics UTM campaign tracking not working with iOS

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I am using React Native to build an app. I track events and other metrics with Firebase.

I would like to launch a custom campaign (newsletters, newspaper ads, etc.)
I am trying to track app installs (first_open) on iOS and Android and I am still unable to track iOS installs.
I tried with https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns but the url generated is not working and for me it is weird that this form require Google Analytics Property ID.

Anyone know how to build this kind of URL?